# Subsetting a DocuementTermMatrix

Tags: r, tm

I have created a TermDocumentMatrix that looks something like this:

```
>inspect(tdm[1:6,1:3])   
Terms       Doc1.txt   Doc2.txt    Doc3.txt
abcd          1           0          0
abandon       0           1          1
qrd           0           0          1
abductor      1           0          0 
plo           1           1          0
man           0           1          0
```

I also have a list  of words something like:

```
>dict
abductor
abandon
man
mammoth
```

Now how do I subset the TermDocumentMatrix rows so that it looks like

```
Terms       Doc1.txt   Doc2.txt    Doc3.txt
abandon       0           1          1
abductor      1           0          0
```

I am only able to check the row names in matrix with the 'dict' list, but I'm unable to subset them

Answer (score 2):

You can subset with a vector of words. You didn't include a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so I'll just use the one from the `?TermDocumentMatrix` help page.

```
library(tm)
data("crude")
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(crude,
    control = list(removePunctuation = TRUE,
    stopwords = TRUE))

words<-c("world","zero")
inspect(tdm[words, 1:3])

# <<TermDocumentMatrix (terms: 2, documents: 3)>>
# Non-/sparse entries: 1/5
# Sparsity           : 83%
# Maximal term length: 5
# Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
# 
#        Docs
# Terms   127 144 191
#   world   0   1   0
#   zero    0   0   0
```

If you don't know which of the words appears in the matrix, you can use

```
words <- c("world","zero", "xyyzy")
inspect(tdm[words[words %in% Terms(tdm)], 1:3])
```

Comment: if I try words<-c('world','zero','xyyzy') in your code snippet I get an error      Error in `[.simple_triplet_matrix`(tdm, words, 1:3) : 
  Subscript out of bounds. I want check the words in the rows of the dataframe with a given list

Comment: That was not very clear from your question. I've updated the answer to subset the word list to only those words in the matrix.

Comment: Apologies, but the modified answer works great, thanks